# Digging along side of garage footer

Tags: foundation

I want to remove a deck from the back of my garage and drop the area to be level with my pool patio. I’m thinking maybe 20-30” would need to be removed and I would be below the exaisting footer... I have had 2 contractors tell me that I could just build a small retaining wall about 18-24” away from the wall to keep the dirt along the footer and keep it from freezing ...

Will a small wall work? Or would I need to underpin the foundation

I’m in upstate NY btw

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's tough to know what the exact situation is; perhaps a diagram or picture would help.

Comment: Are you planning to remove a complete wall width? Or a smaller half width? Retaining wall may not hold the garage depending on construction of it.